# Expander y DataGrid con c#, ejecutar un evento dentro de otro

Tags: c#, .net, eventos, datagrid

Expongo mi caso, tengo un Expander que empieza cerrado, yo lo expando y con ello relleno un DataGrid.

Mi problema:

Al presionar sobre una fila del DataGrid, quiero que el Expander se cierre, por ello pongo en el evento 
`SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)`
el código
`Expander_Collapsed(null, null);`
para que se ejecute el evento Collapsed y esto ejecuta el código que esta en el evento pero no ejecuta realmente el evento porque luego el Expander no funciona del todo, y no soy capaz de convertir el `SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs` en `RoutedEventArgs` para que el evento funcione correctamente.

¿Hay algún método para convertir uno en otro ó qué hago para que ejecute el evento correctamente?

El código de los eventos del Expander:

```
private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
GridBus.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
}
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
 GridBus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

El código del evento del DataGrid:

```
public void Seleccionar(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e){ 
Expander_Collapsed(null, null);
}
```

Esto funciona porque solo se ejecuta el código del Expander_Collapsed no el evento en si, es decir, la funcionalidad inherente que yo no programo, puedo en vez de poner, `Expander_Collapsed(null, null);` poner `Expander_Collapsed(sender, e);`
pero la `e` da error, de hay mi pregunta si se puede convertir de un tipo a otro o hay otra manera de llevar a cabo lo que yo quiero hacer.

Explicacion gráfica:
[image: Proceso por pasos]

En el paso 2, (la imagen 2) es cuando clico sobre una fila

Comment: Creo que lo primero que debes hacer es mostrar tu código, para ver como realizas la programación dentro de tu método `Expander_Collapsed` y en el evento del `DataGridView` `SelectedCellsChanged`

Comment: **Prueba ejecutar tu evento de esta manera: `Expander_Collapsed(sender, null);`**  _tengo un Expander que empieza cerrado, yo lo expando y con ello relleno un DataGrid._ No termino de entender bien lo que explicas aqui _Al presionar sobre una fila del DataGrid, quiero que el Expander se cierre_ si cierras el expander entonces el grid no estaría visible, esa parte no termino de comprenderla. Y cuando envias `Expander_Collapsed(null, null);` el evento se ejecuta pero le estas diciendo no hagas nada.

Comment: No tengo como probar tu código pero otra cosa que se me ocurre es que en el evento de tu `DataGridView` hagas algo como esto, para probar que sucede: 

`public void Seleccionar(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e){ 
    var customEvento = e as RoutedEventArgs;
    if (null != customEvento){
        Expander_Collapsed(sender, customEvento);
    }
}`  Pruebe también sin la validación `if (null != customEvento)`

Comment: La solución que propones me da un error porque no me deja convertir `SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs` en `RoutedEventArgs`, he actualizado el post para que con una foto entiendas bien lo que ocurre

Comment: Eso supuse, porque tendría que derivar de ella, pero una pregunta porque usas `RoutedEventArgs` no puedes manejar otro evento para el expander, y viendo tu imagen, creo que lo que quieres decir es lo siguiente: **Cuando des click en el expander llenara el datagridview, luego cuando selecciones una fila cerrara el expander, ocultara el grid y cargara los datos en los demas controles de la pantalla?**